# libFlac example can't encode mono wav file

Tags: audio, wav, encode, avaudiorecorder

I'm using [libFlac](http://flac.sourceforge.net/) to convert a mono wave file to flac.

I'm using a sample file from the wav section in wikipedia, that can be [downloaded here](http://www.nch.com.au/acm/8k16bitpcm.wav)

The [example code](http://awesome-wav.googlecode.com/svn-history/r263/trunk/src/flac/main.c) that comes with libFlac says in the documentation that it only supports 16-bit stereo files.

According to libFlac documentation, the library supports 1-8 channels, so there shouldn't be any problem.

I tried changing the example code to simply allow encoding a mono file by simply replacing the lines

```
//channels = 2;
channels = 1;
```

The rest of the code looks like it should support one channel without any problems, but when I try to encode a mono file I get a corrupted audio. (The original audio but with "holes" in the audio).

Does any one have a libFlac example that supports encoding a mono file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was the sample rate. The mono wav file I was using had sample rate of 8000, and when I encoded it to a flac with a sample rate of 8000 the audio is corrupted, even when using utilities like [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)

When I encoded the wav into a flac file with a sample rate of 16000, the file was encoded correctly.

I'll post an issue to libFlack about this matter.